# Consolidate similar methods into a single method to reduce duplication

Tags: c#, oop, methods, coding-efficiency

I'm trying to learn and practice OOP principles and I need some help with an example to get me over the hump.  I have the following code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            dictionary.Add("cat", "one");
            dictionary.Add("dog", "two");
            dictionary.Add("llama", "three");
            dictionary.Add("iguana", "four");

            var test1 = GetKVP(dictionary, "llama");
            var test2 = GetValue(dictionary, "llama");
            var test3 = GetPosition(dictionary, "llama");
        }

        static KeyValuePair<string, string> GetKVP(Dictionary<string, string> dict, string key_to_find)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in dict)
            {
                if (kvp.Key == key_to_find)
                {return kvp;}
            }
            return new KeyValuePair<string, string>();
        }

        static string GetValue(Dictionary<string, string> dict, string key_to_find)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in dict)
            {
                if (kvp.Key == key_to_find)
                {return kvp.Value;}
            }
            return string.Empty;
        }

        static int GetPosition(Dictionary<string, string> dict, string key_to_find)
        {
            int counter = 0;
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in dict)
            {
                if (kvp.Key == key_to_find)
                {return counter;}
                counter += 1;
            }
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is consolidate the code set so that I can have a single method which returns a different data type without duplicating code.  **Please don't comment on the fact that there are several more efficient ways to search a dictionary, I'm aware that this is not ideal.. I simply mocked up some data and methods to use as an example.** For the life of me, I can't really visualize how to implement something like that.

Comment: Dictionaries are not ordered, so GetPosition won't return consistent results, except by coincidence.

Comment: It's just an example "Please don't comment on the fact that there are several more efficient ways to search a dictionary, I'm aware that this is not ideal.. I simply mocked up some data and methods to use as an example.".. I don't really care what it returns, I just needed a method that returns something.

Comment: This code doesn't make any sense to me. In addition to the point in the previous comment (`GetPosition()` is a nonsense method), what's the point of `GetKVP()`? When is it ever useful to have an empty instance of `KeyValuePair` (even assuming you fixed the code so it would compile...there's no parameterless constructor for that type). What are you actually trying to consolidate here? Are you just looking to make this code _generic_?

Comment: Your example has to make at least a _little_ bit of sense, otherwise the question itself can't make any sense. This is not a matter of the code being "not ideal". It's a matter of the code not even doing anything useful.

Comment: What duplication are you talking about?

Comment: I guess I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to write a single method (e.g.. "SearchNFetch") which can return either a KVP a string or an int (**FOR EXAMPLE**) depending on what I need to get back.  The loop is supposed to represent the duplication as each method is looping through the dictionary exactly the same, just returning a different data type and I wanted to see if there was a way to eliminate that duplication.

Comment: Frequently such searches done with LINQ - so you can look into signature/implementation of `Enumerable.Where`...

Comment: In .net everthing is based on Object, so just return Object and then object could be anything just as you want

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In .net everthing is based on Object, so just return Object and then object could be anything just as you want

here is a sample based on your code

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Dictionary<string, Object> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            dictionary.Add("cat", "one");
            dictionary.Add("dog", "two");
            dictionary.Add("llama", "three");
            dictionary.Add("iguana", "four");

            var test1 = GetWhatEver(dictionary, "llama");
            var test2 = GetWhatEver(dictionary, "llama");
            var test3 = GetWhatEver(dictionary, "llama");
        }

         static Object GetWhatEver(Dictionary<string, Object> dict, string key_to_find)
        {
            foreach (var kvp in dict)  
            {
                if (kvp.Key == key_to_find)
                {return kvp.Value;}
            }
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is what I was envisioning. but how do I indicate to the method what it should return then?  For instance, say I want the object to be a string.. should I just add a parameter to indicate that?

Comment: you can add anything to the dictionary and then it returns the thing you have added , to use the returned object in a proper way is up to the rest of your code

Comment: Sorry.. what I mean is.. in some instances I want to hunt for and receive back the whole kvp, but in some instances I want it to only return me the string etc.

Comment: would something like "static Object GetWhatEver(Dictionary<string, string> dict, string key_to_find, Type T)" work, then have an if statement that returns me the type of object I want ???

Comment: well since your method now returns object you could add some logic to it that retruns either the kvp or the object from the kvp.

Comment: yes that would probably work, although I think it will be rather messy , wouldn't it be better to always return the kvp , and then make the rest of your logic to decide if it needs the whole thing or just he object ?

Comment: oh, definitely.. I have a **MUCH** more complex situation in my real solution.  I just wanted to simplify the "spirit" of what I'm trying to do to get a feel for the "correct" way to implement something like this only for the purposes of an example for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing this, but I don't think it helps too much:

```
static R GetResult<R>(Dictionary<string, string> dict, string key_to_find, Func<KeyValuePair<string, string>, R> selector, R otherwise)
{
    return dict.Where(kvp => kvp.Key == key_to_find).Select(kvp => selector(kvp)).DefaultIfEmpty(otherwise).First();
}

static KeyValuePair<string, string> GetKVP(Dictionary<string, string> dict, string key_to_find)
{
    return GetResult(dict, key_to_find, kvp => kvp, new KeyValuePair<string, string>());
}

static string GetValue(Dictionary<string, string> dict, string key_to_find)
{
    return GetResult(dict, key_to_find, kvp => kvp.Value, String.Empty);
}

static int GetPosition(Dictionary<string, string> dict, string key_to_find)
{
    return dict.Where(kvp => kvp.Key == key_to_find).Select((kvp, n) => n).DefaultIfEmpty(-1).First();
}
```